# Identifying the next character in a string is capital or not

Tags: c++, string, char, compiler-theory

I am writing a C++ program. I have an array of char array trans[20][100]. Actually each string of trans is a transition of a grammar(Programming language translators). I want to check for each string in trans whether there is a Non-terminal after a '.' i.e. i want to check if in the strings there is a '.' followed by any capital letter. Can anyone please tell me how to do it??
-Thanks in advance

Comment: Please dont tell me to use Strings in C++. I need help with this only.

Comment: can you post some code of what you already tried or be more precise what your concrete problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you operate on ASCII char, then you could test if the int value of the char is between 65 and 90. See [the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: For readability it is better to compare with the `char` literals `'A'` and `'Z'`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use any RegExp library (e.g. [this one](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html)). The test regular expression is `/\.[A-Z]/`.

Or for ASCII string you can use:

```
int strHasDotCap(const char *s)
{
    while (*s) {
        if (*s++ == '.') {
            if (*s >= 'A' && *s <= 'Z') return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Regex is a good idea for tokenization (which seems to be what OP is trying to do), but it's plain overkill for something this simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the functions in ctype.h isAlpha(), isUpper() etc. if the characters are ASCII type.